# Bootstrap navbars collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am new to Bootstrap and so far I cannot find a solution to my problem. I have one navbar on the header of my page, it has multiple menu items and on smaller screens it collapses into the "hamburger"-style button. So far so good. BUT, on one of my sub-pages I have another navbar on the top with just couple of options and I do not need this one to collapse at all even on smallest screens. So, overwriting css for all navbars will not work in my case... Any idea if this can be done at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As you can see in this **bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/ZhmRJQI7GD , the first navbar collapse, and not the second...*

**CSS**:

```
#secondNav{
    margin-top:5em;
}


#secondNav .navbar-nav>li {
 float: left !important; 
}
#secondNav .navbar-header{
  float: left !important; 
}
#secondNav .navbar-nav{
   margin:0 !important;
}
#secondNav .navbar-nav>li a{
  padding-top: 15px !important;
padding-bottom: 15px !important; 
}
```

**HTML** :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="secondNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Two</a>
  </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, it does collapse... It does not convert into "hamburger" button, but on extra-small screens options are listed one per line and this is what I am trying to avoid.